# How to extract email addresses from an E-Mail folder on the server

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I am now in the situation where I need to complete my Rspamd Blocklist with the domains that are spamming me. As I cannot do this direct from my inbox, I have now the following setup:

1. I mark all emails as Junk and they land in the Junk folder.
2. I go through the junk folder, selecting the domain of the sender and adding this to the rspamd blocklist one by one

I would like if there is any automated way how I can extract all the "from" email adresses from a folder on the server and to throw them into for example a .csv file. To the email server I have IMAP and POP access.

Many thanks!

Comment: You forgot to specify your email client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most "From" addresses are short-lived and not worth blocking one by one. Focus on automated detection such as Rspamd's support for SPF, DNSBL, and auto-learning features instead. (Besides that, the "From" header in the message will often not actually match the SMTP Mail-From envelope header which is slightly more useful to block.)

If your mail server stores the messages in Maildir format, an easy way to get all of their "From" headers is to just run `grep -r "^From:" ~/Mail/.Junk/`. (The same applies to mbox-format folders... not that you should use mbox.) This is not as precise as a real RFC2822 header parser, but often it's good enough.

For something more precise, a very short Python script using the [mailbox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html) module can parse the messages:

```
for msg in mailbox.Maildir("/home/foo/Mail/.Junk/"):
    print(msg["From"])
```

If the mail server uses a custom storage format (like Dovecot's dbox), use Mutt or Thunderbird to copy all those messages via IMAP to a local folder – both of those clients use Maildir or mbox for local folders, so now you have an already solved problem.

Comment: python on a local folder sounds like a good idea. I will try that. Many thanks!